# How to add image analysis results into dataframe in python (for a confusion matrix)?

Tags: python, image-processing, confusion-matrix

New in Python, I try to determine the efficiency of a color segmentation function on my samples by doing a confusion matrix. The color segmentation function`green_detection` is as follows:

```
import cv2
from skimage import io

def green_detection(img):

    #converting the picture to HSV  
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

    #defining HSV limits
    lower_green = (40, 25, 100)
    upper_green = (80, 255, 255)

    #creating a mask with the limits and calculating green area fraction
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_green, upper_green)

    mask_pix = (mask == 255).sum()
    green_area = mask_pix / (mask.shape[0]*mask.shape[1]) * 100

    #value of acceptable green area on the picture in %
    acceptable_green_area = 0.5

    #sort the picture based on the green area
    if green_area < acceptable_green_area:
        print ('Green not detected')
    else:
        print ('Green detected')
```

I then run the function for all my samples:

```
path = "green\\sample"

list_samples = []
for i in range(1, 201):
    img = io.imread(path + str(i) + ".tif")
    list_samples.append(img)
    green_haze_detection(img)
```

I wish to create a dataframe with the sample name (1st column) and the result of the function for the 200 samples I have (2nd column): when detecting green, add 1 to the row. When not, add 0.
This will later be merge with an existing excel file to create a confusion matrix.
Could you please give me a piece of advice to automate the data collection?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a confusion matrix is by using `sklearn`. `actual` are the actual outputs (either `0` or `1`); `predicted` are the predicted outputs (either `0` or `1`).

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

Confusionmatrix = confusion_matrix(actual, predicted)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips ! I will definitely use it once I know how to make batch sample analysis

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I figured out the problems:

```
#First of all, create a return for the function:
if area < min_green_haze_area: 
    return 0
else:
    return 1

#Create a list of header:
name_feature = ['Image n°', 'green_haze_detection']

#Then create an empty dataframe:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=name_feature)

#Create a variable in which I can store my function results:
GD = green_detection(img)

#create a new line for each analysis, create a row and append it to the dataframe:
new_line = [i] + [GD]
row = pd.Series(new_line, name_feature)
df = df.append([row], ignore_index=True)
```

Now it runs and I get the results of my analysis in a dataframe. I will now use to make a confusion matrix using sklearn